# Clear database before testcase espresso

Tags: android, kotlin, ui-automation, android-espresso

im using espresso to clear database in my app
Im setting activity like this

```
@Rule
@JvmField
val activity = ActivityTestRule<PhotoPrinterActivity>(PhotoPrinterActivity::class.java,false,false)
```

And this is my before function

```
@Before
open fun setup() {
    clearDatabase()
    activity.launchActivity(null)
    // Waiting for start app success fully

}
```

And this is my clear database code

```
fun clearDatabase() {
    val databaseList = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext.databaseList()
    for (database in databaseList) {

        // when transaction rollback files exists they are always locked so we can't delete them
        if (database.contains(".db-journal")) {
            InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().deleteDatabase(database)
            continue
        }

        // when using transaction write ahead logging then this db files are listed but often they don't exist
        if (database.contains(".db-wal") || database.contains(".db-shm")) {
            InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().deleteDatabase(database)
            continue
        }
        Log.v("EspressoMacchiato", "deleting " + database)
        var databasePath = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext.getDatabasePath(database)
        if (databasePath.exists()) {
            InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext.deleteDatabase(database)
        }
    }

}
```

Issue is when clear database success and perform add some data into database,

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:786)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
```

Anyone please help me !Thanks so much!

Comment: The delete operation may be placing a lock on the database file, which is why you would see this error. 

Try post a delay on your activity launch to test if that is the case.

Comment: can you post your database code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) and [InstrumentationRegistry](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry.html) in your espresso tests to delete database:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() {
    InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().deleteDatabase("database_name");
}
```

And to prevent bugs when executing multiple espresso tests at once, use [Android Test Orchestrator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html#using-android-test-orchestrator). It will execute all of them separately.

Answer (score 2):

In case you can't make the accepted answer work due to deprecation I believe the Instrumentation api was updated to:
InstrumentationRegistry **.getInstrumentation()** .getTargetContext()

therefore:

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().deleteDatabase("database_name")
```

Alternatively you can get the actual application context (the "target") you can do :

```
ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<YOUR-APPLICATION>().deleteDatabase("database_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Clearing the database once per test class**

Add the following code to your Android Test class:

```
companion object {
    @BeforeClass
    fun clearDatabase() {
        InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().uiAutomation.executeShellCommand("pm clear PACKAGE_NAME").close()
    }
}
```

### **Clearing the database before every test**

An alternative way to have the database cleared before each test run is to set the clearPackageData flag while using [Android Test Orchestrator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#ato-gradle). This will "remove all shared state from your device's CPU and memory after each test:"

> Add the following statements to your project's build.gradle file:
>
> ```
> android {
>   defaultConfig {
>    ...
>    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
>
>    // The following argument makes the Android Test Orchestrator run its
>    // "pm clear" command after each test invocation. This command ensures
>    // that the app's state is completely cleared between tests.
>    testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
>  }
>
>   testOptions {
>     execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
>   }
> }
>
> dependencies {
>   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
>   androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.1.0'
> }
> ```